# TopMost not working when tabbing

Tags: c#, winforms

A few minutes ago I encountered a weird problem with TopMost. I created a topmost form (WinForms) did some tabbing and everything was fine.

Then I tried to open a computer game (fullscren-windowed) which means the game is fullscreen but in a windowed mode which means you can still overlay it with forms. Everything fine until I opened my Browser for example (could be any other program (editor)). Just as a quick side note I have two monitors.

1. I tabbed out of the computer game (where my form is TopMost) into the browser
2. I clicked somewhere in the browser (url)
3. I tabbed back into the game, clicked somewhere in the game (my form is still TopMost)
4. I do step 1-3 again and suddenly my form (topmost) disappeared.

This happens every time I do this and this problem can be reproduced on at least 2 other 
machines.

**EDIT:**

I tried to implement the suggested solution

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    public void setTOP()
    {
        SetWindowPos(this.Handle, new IntPtr(-1), 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.setTOP();
    }
}
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a horrible solution but it's better than nothing so far.

I implemented a timer which calls topmost every x seconds. Just like I said, it's not a good solution but the only one which came to my mind. I'll continue to work on this but for the meantime this is what i do.

Answer (score 1):

The topMost API just set the order of windows. I recommend to just call the "TopMost" flag again. `TopMost = False` `TopMost = True` to reset the order. Because another window can use the same command to the OS.

Background working API (just for information)

```
Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
                 ByVal hwnd As integer, _
                 ByVal hWndInsertAfter As integer, _
                 ByVal x As integer, _
                 ByVal y As integer, _
                 ByVal cx As integer, _
                 ByVal cy As integer, _
                 ByVal wFlags As integer) As integer
```

http://www.activevb.de/cgi-bin/apiwiki/SetWindowPos

Regards

Comment: how do I know when to call topmost again??? since the form isn't focused or anything I don't know when it goes to the background/disappears... I also tried to use SetWindowPos doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hi Layne. Here in my case it works. Please, can you tell me if there is any game which is using DirectX or some graphic accelerated videos or something similar? Perhaps the video acceleration is a problem? The same problem was here (German) and was solved using the code below: http://www.activevb.de/tipps/vb6tipps/tipp0007.html

Comment: The game I tested it with is StarCraft 2. Maybe I didn't implement it correctly but since it was topmost except for this scenario i don't think I did a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to call topmost again whenever your application gets focus.

Comment: 1. How is it supposed to get focused if it is not visible 2. It's a little bit annoying for the user to focus it every time he tabs.